# Trying to make a mobile off-canvas slideout that pushes the main content off the screen

Tags: css, html, sass

I'm working on a demo that will use pure CSS to push content off the screen when a menu button is toggled. This will be for a slideout mobile navigation menu.

I'm using as a starting point the example here:

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/umEgv

The author creates a navigation div and a content div. Initially the navigation div has 0 width and the content div has 100% like so:

```
.page-wrap {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3B3B3B;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
```

Then when you click on the menu toggle button he changes the width dimensions to 20% and 80% respectively.

```
#main-nav:target {
  width: 20%;
}
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
  width: 80%;
}
```

That all works really well but instead of pushing the .page-wrap div off the screen it just reduces the width. This looks really strange, I'd much rather just push it off the screen. I tried adding overflow-x: hidden to the body and removing the explicitly width on the .page-wrap section, but that didn't work.

```
.page-wrap {
      float: right;
      transition: width 0.3s ease;
    }


body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#main-nav:target {
  width: 40%;
}
#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
  .open-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .close-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-header {
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

Is it because the position of the #main-nav is set to "fixed" and so therefore it can't "push" the page-wrap div because its outside the normal flow of the document? If so how do I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance, you should use CSS transforms when available. This tutorial uses a technique similar to Chris Coyiers, but with a lot more detail, some fallbacks for older browsers, etc.

http://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms

It's the most clearly written tutorial on the topic I've seen so far. Here's a working demo of the result: http://codepen.io/ncerminara/full/KJjiD/

**Edit**

Adding a bit more detail on the difference in approach. With the article I linked above, you're positioning the hidden navigation elements offscreen with negative margins. When you activate a navigation area, you're not changing their margin, but actually shifting the entire canvas over a certain amount—exposing the navigation, and hiding part of the main content in the process.

Comment: Great answer, and the tutorial you linked to is excellent! Going to use a similar approach here. Thanks!

Comment: Hey that's me! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the width of the element, you should animate the position - of course you'll have to make it absolutely positioned. You could mess around with animating the padding or something as well. Then just hide the overflow once it's pushed off screen.

Right now, there isn't any overflow so thats why that's not working. It's just reducing the width of the element which is relative to the screen anyway.

Don't forget to change the transition declaration as well, could probably just go with all.

Code below, only left the stuff that I changed from that pen

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }

.page-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.main-nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#main-nav:target + .page-wrap {
  left: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Obviously it's not totally advisable to have overflow: hidden on your entire page but I just added that there as a quick fix to demonstrate.